# Access-Control-Allow-Origin not working as expected, allowing all traffic

Tags: security, nginx, http-headers, csrf

I am testing a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` http response header security policy in `nginx` with:

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://google.com";
```

I would expect requests to then fail on my domain, however they are working, returning a 200 status code. I confirm that indeed the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header is being set:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://google.com
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 05 Feb 2013 20:22:17 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:nginx
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31556926
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Frame-Options:DENY
```

And the request header shows the correct origin:

```
Origin:https://mydomainhere.com
```

Any idea what could be causing this? I would expect requests to fail.

Thanks.

Comment: how are u making the request ? are you making XMLHttpRequest request.

Comment: Yes I am making an AJAX request, see a full request with all headers as a Gist: https://gist.github.com/nodesocket/4745284

Comment: i am writing comment since i am not sure i understood the question. your first page came from <mydomain>, which contain Ajax call (XhttpRequest), in response to XhttpResponse you are setting access-control-allow-orgin to <google.com>. Now you are expecting XhttpRequest to fail ? is this correct ?

Comment: It is my understanding that yes, since I have set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin is https://google.com, AJAX requests originating from `mydomain.com` should fail. Basically I am looking at implementing this as a way to mitigate CSRF attacks. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- server(webserver like nginx) has nothing to do with access-control-allow-origin(other then setting or unsetting the flag). It is a direction to  browser to allow cross domain Ajax (XhttpRequest) calls.
- so when you are setting access-control-allow-origin to google.com, you are telling the bowser to allow Ajax call to google.com from page from your site.

go through - [HTTP access control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) for more details.

Comment: Ok, confirmed that AJAX requests fail, but cross origin <img> requests still work. Any way to fail those as well?